# Java alternative Observer Pattern

Tags: java, observer-pattern

In my Object Oriented Lecture at the University I encountered a strange Observer-Pattern which differs from the ones which I see online.

Instead of seperating the Observable and Observer in two different Objects there is one big Object which combines the two. Additionally, the Superobject got a method, which returns the observer (as a handle).

My lecturer told me that this way of implementing the pattern would solve an architectural issue which would cause the update-method to explode if we extend it. I think I get most of his intention.

My issue right now is, that I got no other source to learn about this 'alternative' Observer-Pattern, or at least I'm not able to find an article about the pattern. Though I think I get the point of my lecturer, I don't think I fully understand this patttern, i.e. the benefits of compress all classes together.

Can anybody elaborate, why this architecture would benefit my code? Or why can't I simply extract the logic of the update-method out into an utility class?

Below is the (java) class which we built. I deleted some of the unnecessary logic.

```
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class Server implements InterfaceServer {
    public Client client;
    private final ObjServer oServer;

    public Server() {
        oServer = new ObjServer();
        new Thread(server).start();
    }

    public Client connect() throws InterruptedException {
        Client handle = new Client();
        oServer.addObserver(handle);
        return handle;
    }

    public class ObjServer extends Observable implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                // pull data

                setChanged();
                notifyObservers(m);
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Client implements Observer {

        private Object obj;
        private Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(0, true);

        public Object getObject() throws InterruptedException {
            semaphore.acquire();
            System.out.println(obj);

            return obj;
        }

        @Override
        public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
            obj = arg;
            semaphore.release();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        Server server = new Server();

        Client client = new Client();

        client = server.connect();

        while (true) {
            client.getObject();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Client implements Observer` and `ObjServer extends Observable`; they are separate classes, not combined. Or do you mean that they are both declared/enclosed within the `Server` class?

Comment: There is 'one big object' which *contains,* lexically, an `Observer` and an `Observable.` It doesnt 'combine the two,' and it doesn't solve any specific problem that I can see. You need to know that `Observer` and `Observable` are very little used in Java. I've never used them in 18 years.

Comment: And there *are* use cases, where observer-observable-hybrids *would be* very rational and applicable: e.g. a kind of "p2p-observation".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how this differs from the traditional observer pattern. You still have one observable object: `ObjServer`, and an observer object: `Client`. And the observable has a method to add observers, and it calls back the added observers.

How these objects are created and who creates them is irrelevant to the observer pattern.

Note that these lines:

```
Client client = new Client();
client = server.connect();
```

make little sense. Why do you create a new Client, and immediately throw it away and reassign the client returned by server.connect() to the variable? You could simply do

```
Client client = server.connect();
```